# Bibtex: Wrong parsed page

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I have following bibtex entry:

```
@inproceedings{kriegler1969preprocessing,
    title={Preprocessing transformations and their effects on multispectral recognition},
    author={Kriegler, FJ and Malila, WA and Nalepka, RF and Richardson, W},
    booktitle={Remote Sensing of Environment, VI},
    volume={1},
    pages={97},
    year={1969}
}
```

In my bibliography (apalike2) this is displayed as
[image: bib]
How I can remove the "~" above the 9? This error occurs only, if I cite a single page

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@inproceedings{kriegler1969preprocessing,
    title={Preprocessing transformations and their effects on multispectral recognition},
    author={Kriegler, FJ and Malila, WA and Nalepka, RF and Richardson, W},
    booktitle={Remote Sensing of Environment, VI},
    volume={1},
    pages={97},
    year={1969}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    \cite{kriegler1969preprocessing}

    \bibliographystyle{apalike2}
    \bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal document?

Comment: Hi there. I think we need a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your setup. My guess would be that you load `babel` package with some "exotic" language such as Spanish, but I can be completely wrong.

Comment: Added it, but there is nothing special

Comment: Side remark: pages should not be used for pages you *cite* (what will you do if you cite 5 different pages of the article?).  pages describes the location of the article in the collection. So pages={97} makes only sense if the article is only one page long. The page you cite should be added at the `\cite`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in `apalike2.bst`; line 510 reads

```
510         { "(pp.\" pages tie.or.space.connect }
```

(line number added for reference) so when there is only one page number and not a range, in the `.bbl` file

```
pp.\~97
```

is written, as in your case. This is of course very wrong.

Make a copy of `apalike2.bst` in your working directory, naming it `fixed-apalike2.bst` and change line 510 to read

```
         { "(p." pages tie.or.space.connect }
```

Change your call to be

```
\bibliographystyle{fixed-apalike2}
```

The entry in the `.bbl` file will become

```
\bibitem[Kriegler et~al., 1969a]{kriegler1969preprocessing}
Kriegler, F., Malila, W., Nalepka, R., \& Richardson, W. (1969a).
\newblock Preprocessing transformations and their effects on multispectral
  recognition.
\newblock In {\em Remote Sensing of Environment, VI}, volume~1  (p.~97).
```